# Show $\mathrm{Core}_S(H)$ is the biggest

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For a group $G$, the normal core of a subgroup $H$ is the largest normal subgroup of G that is contained in $H$

$\mathrm{Core}_S(H) := \bigcap_{s \in S}{s^{-1}Hs}.$

I got this from wikipedia, but it has no proof. How does one proof the $\mathrm{Core}_S(H)$ is the largest?

I suppose I can say,

Suppose their existed another normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$, say $N$.
But I don't know how to show $$\mathrm{Core}_S(H) =N$$

How can i start?

$$\mathrm{Core}_S(H) \subseteq N$$

$$N \subseteq\mathrm{Core}_S(H)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N$ is normal in $G$ and is contained in $H$, $xNx^{-1}\subseteq xHx^{-1}$ for each $x\in G$. And $xNx^{-1}=N$ by normality, so?

Comment: $N\subseteq core(H)$: Since $N$ is normal, $\forall a\in G,$    $aNa^{-1} = N$ Hence $N = aNa^{-1}\subseteq aHa^{-1}\subseteq Core(H)$.

Comment: $Core(H)\subseteq N$: Let $c \in Core(H)$, then $c = x^{-1}hx$ for some $x\in G$ and $h\in H$.Since $N \leq H$ we can restrict $h$ to lie $\in N$. so $ c = x^{-1}hx \in N$ since $N$ is normal.

Comment: Does this look good?

Comment: @abe15 The first comment is wrong. The core is an intersection, not a union, so the last inclusion should go the other way around.